# AspNetCore.Authorization: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configure')'

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm getting an exception while trying to run the .net 3.1 application.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build(); --> Exception here!
```

Here is the exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configure')'
```

Not sure what is the problem?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization; (Version=5.0.0.0)
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;

services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved by downgrading the nuget package of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` from 5.0.0 into 3.1.0 (the project is .net-core 3.1).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - update all Microsoft.AspNetCore.* packages in all projects to 5.* or 6.* versions.
I did update up to 6.0.* and it is working now.
I assume that 3* is not compatible with 5 and 6 versions of Microsoft.AspNetCore subpackages.